# What to do in the Fragment onCreateView Method?

Tags: android, android-fragments

What I have are 3 Layouts.
`fragment_tag`, `fragment_stunde` and `fragment_fach`

`fach` should be in `stunde` and `stunde` in `tag`.

And in fach are some `TextView`s I want to set the text.

So my code so far is:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout tag = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tag, container, true);

        database = new Database(context);

        database.open();

        for (int j = 1; j < 12; j++) {
            LinearLayout stunde = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stunde, tag, true);
            String[][] vplanDaten = database.getVplan(Integer.valueOf(DateHelper.get(DateHelper.WEEK_OF_YEAR)), index + 1, j);

            for (int k = 0; k < vplanDaten.length; k++) {
                LinearLayout fach = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fach, stunde, true);

                TextView fach_lehrer = (TextView) fach.findViewById(R.id.textView_lehrer);
                TextView fach_fach = (TextView) fach.findViewById(R.id.textView_fach);
                TextView fach_raum = (TextView) fach.findViewById(R.id.textView_raum);

                fach_lehrer.setText(vplanDaten[k][0]);
                fach_fach.setText(vplanDaten[k][1]);
                fach_raum.setText(vplanDaten[k][2]);
            }
        }
        database.close();
        return tag;
    }
```

But this gives me an Error:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
        at de.MayerhoferSimon.Vertretungsplan.TagFragment.onCreateView(TagFragment.java:56)
```

So how do I have to change the code that that what I want to do happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the following changes:

```
LinearLayout tag = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tag, container, true);
```

to:

```
LinearLayout tag = (LinearLayout)(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tag, null)).findViewById(R.id.idOfTag);
```

Similarly:

```
LinearLayout stunde = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stunde, tag, true);
```

to:

```
LinearLayout stunde = (LinearLayout)(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stunde, null)).findViewById(R.id.idOfStunde);
```

And:

```
LinearLayout fach = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fach, stunde, true);
```

to:

```
LinearLayout fach = (LinearLayout)(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fach, null)).findViewById(R.id.idOfFach);
```

Comment: and than just call ```ViewGroup.addView()```?

Comment: @Simon no. As you said, `fach should be in stunde and stunde in tag` --> `stunde.addView(fach);` `tag.addView(stunde);` <- And you are already returning `tag`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `LinearLayout` to a View like such:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View tag = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tag, container, true);
       //Everything else...
    return tag;
}
```

Also I believe you can only inflate one view per `onCreateView` otherwise the layouts will replace one another. You need to have three separate fragments that each inflate its own view and call these fragments individually from the top parent activity.

Comment: but I also need a new created layout from the other 2 Views.

Comment: You're right View is redundant. Fragment views should be independent and only communicate to each other through the parent activity.